# Image position is moving when resizing image after rotating canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas, resize

When Resizing image after rotation,image is misplacing or moving in canvas.

```
contextObj.save();
contextObj.translate(ImageX + ImageW / 2, ImageY + ImageH / 2);
contextObj.rotate(angle*Math.PI/180);
contextObj.translate(-(ImageX + ImageW / 2),-(ImageY + ImageH / 2));
contextObj.drawImage(myImage, ImageX, ImageY, ImageW, ImageH);
contextObj.restore();
```

see this Issue here
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariaraj/wh4tqcgr)

i want to resize image without moving or misplace.

Answer (score 0):

```
contextObj.rotate(angle*Math.PI/0);
```

Use this instead of

```
 contextObj.rotate(angle*Math.PI/180);
```

Comment: if i set it to 0 it will not rotate.